# Luxon missing fixedOffSetZone.ts file after installing its type

Tags: typescript, luxon

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/ts-luxon/dist/ts-luxon.es6.js
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCpBi.png)

I faced the above warning message after installing ts-luxon": "^4.3.2" & @types/luxon": "^3.3.1. so, what can I do to remove the warning message from terminal or do I have to rollback to a previous versions